# lvm clone logical volumes layout to another host

Tags: linux, bash, lvm

I want to clone LVM logical volume layout to another host ( = Create volumes with same size ). Does anyone know solution for this ? I know I can execute something like:

```
sudo LC_ALL=C lvs -o lv_name,lv_size,vg_name --units M --noheadings --separator '|' --nosuffix | LC_ALL=C awk -F \| '{ printf("lvcreate -n %s -L %.0fM %s\n",$1,$2,$3) }'
```

to generate commands to execute on another host.

But is there more 'standard' way to perform such task ?

I was browsing through LVM man pages and I found `vgcfgexport` and `vgexport`.
First would export all metadata including stuff like PV UUIDs and second one is used just for moving volume groups, however it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

my volume group use standard `"PE Size  4.00 MB"` in all servers, so the only thing that i need to archive what you want is the number of logical extend of the original volume

```
lvcreate -n volumename -l <number_of_extend_in_the_original_volume> vg00
```